# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =1 address =0x10) in objc

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my NSObject class, I am getting data from my api and returning it in NSString type. When run this same code in iPhone 6/7 or in iOS simulator its working fine. But when i try to run in iPhone 5/5s i am getting this error ( iPhone 5 simulator is also working fine). Is anyone faced this issue before?[image]

Comment: attach your crash log

Comment: If you have code to share with us, please don't post it as image. You can add it to your post and [format it as code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: @NhatDinh nothing is printed in the logs console in Xcode and even i tried NSZombieEnabled also nothing worked.

Comment: What are the values of movieObject resp. movieObject.movieSourceID when you add a breakpoint here? You also might add `NSLog(@"%@", movieObject)` and  `NSLog(@"%@", movieObject.movieSourceID)` before your if statement

Comment: @SanjeevS seem your `movieObject` be dealloced before your `getMovieSourceID` method be called!
You should check where it had been dealloced.

Comment: make sure your object is allocated with init